# Xamarin App won't launch when trying to make popup page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using the Nuget package: `Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages` with this colorPicker: `Spillman.Xamarin.Forms.ColorPicker`.

I created this page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="Memento.Dialogs.ColorPicker"
             xmlns:colorPicker="clr-namespace:Spillman.Xamarin.Forms.ColorPicker;assembly=Spillman.Xamarin.Forms.ColorPicker">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center"
      PositionOut="Center"
      ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8"
      DurationIn="400"
      DurationOut="300"
      EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn"
      HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>

    <pages:PopupPage.BindingContext>
        <colorPicker:ColorPickerViewModel />
    </pages:PopupPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentView HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                 Padding="8" BackgroundColor="White">
        <colorPicker:ColorPickerView />
    </ContentView>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

But when I try to define the page like this: `ColorPicker_Popup = new ColorPicker();` I get the following error:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Resource ID #0x7f0700c3'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do it like this?

```
await PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new ColorPicker(), true);
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. No clue why I couldn't do it my way

Comment: `private ColorPicker ColorPicker_Popup = new ColorPicker();`

Comment: U can't use it like that. ColorPicker is just element off layout not element to navigation. You got colorPicker as content off PopupPage. So you have to open PopupPage to see this view.